# Locating the line number where an exception occurs in python code

Tags: python, exception

I have a code similar to this:

```
try:
  if x:
      statement1
      statement2
      statement3
  elif y:
      statement4
      statement5
      statement6
  else:
      raise

except:
      statement7
```

Here, I am sure that the exception occurs in `If x:` block, but I would like to know in which statement of `If x:` block the exception occurs. Is there a way to get the line number where the exception occurs?

Regards,

Comment: You don't mention why you want this.  For debugging a problem?  So that statement7 can do something different depending on where the exception was raised?  Can you tell us more?

Comment: In my code the exception should not occur in statement 1 or statement 2. if it does, then either of statement1 or 2 is faulty. it is acceptable to have it in statement3. That's why I would like to know in which line there is exception.

Comment: But what will you do with the information?  Do you need it once to fix the program, or do you need it at runtime?

Comment: I need it once to fix the faulty lines. Now I have found the faulty line, thanks all!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

what about this:

```
try:
  if x:
      print 'before statement 1'
      statement1
      print 'before statement 2' #ecc. ecc.
      statement2
      statement3
  elif y:
      statement4
      statement5
      statement6
  else:
      raise

except:
      statement7
```

this is the straightforward workaround but I suggest to use a debugger

or even better, use the sys module :D

```
try:
      if x:
          print 'before statement 1'
          statement1
          print 'before statement 2' #ecc. ecc.
          statement2
          statement3
      elif y:
          statement4
          statement5
          statement6
      else:
          raise
except:
    print sys.exc_traceback.tb_lineno 
    #this is the line number, but there are also other infos
```

Comment: Updating: exc_traceback has been replaced by last_traceback (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)

Answer (score 13):

I believe the several answers here recommending you manage your `try/except` blocks more tightly are the answer you're looking for.   That's a style thing, not a library thing.

However, at times we find ourselves in a situation where it's not a style thing, and you really *do* need the line number to do some other programattic action.   If that's what you're asking, you should consider the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module.  You can extract all the information you need about the most recent exception.  The `tb_lineno` function will return the line number causing the exception.

```
>>> import traceback
>>> dir(traceback)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_format_final_exc_line', '_print', '_some_str', 'extract_stack', 'extract_tb', 'format_exc', 'format_exception', 'format_exception_only', 'format_list', 'format_stack', 'format_tb', 'linecache', 'print_exc', 'print_exception', 'print_last', 'print_list', 'print_stack', 'print_tb', 'sys', 'tb_lineno', 'types']
>>> help(traceback.tb_lineno)
Help on function tb_lineno in module traceback:

tb_lineno(tb)
Calculate correct line number of traceback given in tb.
Obsolete in 2.3
```

Newer versions of the traceback plumbing fix the issue prior to 2.3, allowing the code below to work as it was intended:  (this is the "right way")

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    raise Exception("foo")
except:
    for frame in traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]):
        fname,lineno,fn,text = frame
        print "Error in %s on line %d" % (fname, lineno)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried as you said but I got the following:  exception occured in line number:  <function tb_lineno at 0x2aaaace83140>

Comment: tb_lineno is a function, not an attribute.  It takes the traceback as a parameter.  I edited the post to be more clear.  try "print traceback.tb_lineno(sys.exc_info()[2])" -- make sure to add the paren's.

Answer (score 4):

You should run your program in a debugger, such as [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).  This will allow you to run your code normally, and then examine the environment when something unexpected like this occurs.

Given a script named 'main.py', run it like this:

```
python -m pdb main.py
```

Then, when your program starts, it will start in the debugger.  Type `c` to continue until the next breakpoint (or crash).  Then, you can examine the environment by doing things like `print spam.eggs`.  You can also set breakpoints by doing `pdb.set_trace()` (I commonly do `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`).

Additionally, what do you mean that it is "okay" for 'statement 3' to raise the exception?  Are you expecting the exception?  If so, it might be better to write a try/except block around this statement, so that the program can continue.

Comment: Epic! Worked super awesome with Django, ex. `python -m pdb manage.py syncdb --settings=settings_development` or `python -m pdb manage.py runserver --settings=settings_development`.

Answer (score 3):

I've done the following before:

```
try:
    doing = "statement1"
    statement1
    doing = "statement2"
    statement2
    doing = "statement3"
    statement3
    doing = "statement4"
    statement4

 except:
    print "exception occurred doing ", doing
```

The advantage over printing checkpoints is there's no log output unless
 there actually is an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Building on JJ above..

The advantage of using system errors over statements is they record more specific information which will aid debugging later (believe me I get a lot)

eg. I record them to a text file, so after my programs have automatically run overnight on the server, I can retrieve any issues, and have enough information to quicken the repair!

More Info...  [Traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)  & [Sys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    print 1/0

except Exception as e:
    print '1', e.__doc__
    print '2', sys.exc_info()
    print '3', sys.exc_info()[0]
    print '4', sys.exc_info()[1]
    print '5', sys.exc_info()[2], 'Sorry I mean line...',traceback.tb_lineno(sys.exc_info()[2])
    ex_type, ex, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print '6', traceback.print_tb(tb)
```

Yields

```
>  1  Second argument to a division or modulo operation was zero. 
>  2  (<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('integer division
>      or modulo by zero',), <traceback object at 0x022DCF30>) 
>  3  <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'> 
>  4  integer division or modulo by zero 
>  5  <traceback object at 0x022DCF30> Sorry I mean line... 5
>  6  File "Z:\Programming\Python 2.7\Error.py", line 5, in <module>
>     print 1/0 
      None
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the statements you care about more tightly.  Extracting the line number from the traceback is going to be involved and fragile.

Comment: The question is interesting as is. Even if for ex a debugger could be of better use than printing a traceback. All in all, for me, you are deciding just not to answer. When I come to that question, I am looking for an answer to the title above all, then maybe suggestions about how to code/debug correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you restructure the code like so, you should get a line number when the exception is raised again:

```
except:
    statement7
    raise
```

Comment: I should write "raise" after statement7? Why?

Comment: IF you do it as a temporary debugging change, you should see a detailed stack trace with line numbers when your exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Using a general except statement is usually a bad programming practice, so you should specify in your except statement what exception you want to catch. ( like except ValueError: )

Moreover, you should surround with a try except structure the bits of code that are supposed to be raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your source code, so that you remove one line at a time, until the error disappears, and that should point you closer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

we can get the line number by splitting the string state of the `traceback.format_exc()`.
please try running the following code..

```
import traceback

try:
    a = "str"
    b = 10

    c = a + b
except Exception as e:
    err_lineno = str(traceback.format_exc()).split(",")[1]
    print(err_lineno)
```

this will produce the following output

```
line 7
```