# How to get actual line number of where python exception occurred?

Tags: python, django, exception

I have the following python decorator in my file `decorators.py`

```
def catch_exceptions(function):                                           #Line #1
    @wraps(function)                                                      #Line #2
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):                                       #Line #3
        try:                                                              #Line #4
            return function(*args, **kwargs)                              #Line #5
        except Exception as e:                                            #Line #6
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()                    #Line #7
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]  #Line #8
            print "E=%s, F=%s, L=%s" % (str(e), fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)  #Line #9
    return decorator                                                      #Line #10
```

In another file `my_file.py`, I use the `catch_exceptions` decorator like this:

```
from decorators import catch_exceptions                                   #Line #1
@catch_exceptions                                                         #Line #2
def my_method()                                                           #Line #3
    print (10/0 - 5/0)                                                    #Line #4
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
E=integer division or modulo by zero, F=decorators.py, L=5
```

Instead of it reporting the exception location as `decorators.py`, line #5, How can I get it to report the actual file and line number of where the exception originally occurred? That would be line #4 in `my_file.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it as you described then

```
from functools import wraps
import sys, os, traceback

def catch_exceptions(function):                                           
    @wraps(function)                                                     
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):                                      
        try:                                                              
            return function(*args, **kwargs)                              
        except Exception as e:                                            
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            print "E=%s, F=%s, L=%s" % (str(e), traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1][0], traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1][1]) ) 
    return decorator
```

But it's still [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) that you need to know.

I believe that `filename` that was printing was also a mistake.

So `exc_tb` is actual `traceback` object. And extracting it's data is made by [`extract_tb()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) it will do

> Return a list of up to limit “pre-processed” stack trace entries extracted from the traceback object tb. It is useful for alternate formatting of stack traces. If limit is omitted or `None`, all entries are extracted. A “pre-processed” stack trace entry is a 4-tuple (filename, line number, function name*, text) representing the information that is usually printed for a stack trace.

So the second last element of `traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)` would be exception that is raised in decorator, and the last would be in your function. So the last index(`-1`) is what we need. Then `traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1][0]` would be filename of (I suppose) your desired file, not *decorators.py* and `traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1][1]` would be the line when the exception was fired.

Comment: Yes. This works! FYI, choosing the last element in the traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb) list is even better. It allows this decorator to appear anywhere in the stack of decorators associated with a method. I have accordingly posted an edit to your answer.

Comment: @SaqibAli yeap, that's better, thanks, i approved your edit, but words like _last_, _second_, _first_ need to be handled as well, so i applied another edit! Glad that it helped!

Comment: This answer is the only one I found after more than an hour on SO that actually delivers the exception information from the line where the exception was *raised* instead of where it was caught or called.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into the `traceback` module

```
import traceback

try:
    function_that_raises_exception()
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

It will print the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the line number by splitting the string state of the `traceback.format_exc()`. Please have a look at my answer at the following question, I have added sample code there.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468942/10211611)