# Raising exceptions to find errors in functions

Tags: python, exception

Can this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961750/locating-the-line-number-where-an-exception-occurs-in-python-code) be extended to find the errors at the function level?

I've written code that calls a function I have written.

I can't find where in the function an error is occurring. I've tried using the debugging tools in Spyder, but haven't managed to track the problem down.

I've updated my try-except statement to include the code in the answer above, but it only locates the line number from the code calling the function.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the code.

Comment: Maybe the line that calls the function is where the error is?

Comment: That is not a great answer because it uses a blanket `except` so you have no idea what actually raised the exception. The easy answer is just to get rid of your try/except and see what stack trace you get

Comment: Thanks, I had considered removing my try/except statement, but I was hoping there was another way

Comment: So, outside the debugging stage, you want to see what line raised an error when multiple lines are included in the `try`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use **traceback**:

```
import traceback

def function():
    print("A")
    print(5/0)
    print("C")

try:
    print("A")
    function()
    print("B")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

However, I agree with @roganjosh's comment: I would remove the try/catch and debug the code by letting the exceptions raise where they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

you can raise exception like that:

```
try:
    do_importamt_staff() #your code
except:
    import traceback
    s = traceback.format_exc()
    send_error_message_to_responsible_adult(s)
    raise
```

this code goes to the "error function"(the one which doing the error).

you can read on exceptions in python here: https://www.codementor.io/sheena/how-to-write-python-custom-exceptions-du107ufv9